# C# Webdriver - Upload file(silverlight)

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

My C# webdriver automation script is trying to upload a file using Browse button which is a Silverlight object. Please let me know how to upload a file using webdriver.

Below code worked for HTML file upload but not in case of above scenario.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='fileInput']"), WaitTime).SendKeys("\\\\...\\....\\Test.txt");
```

Comment: How does the element work and look? Is any piece of it accessible through, say, Javascript? Could you click the element, then blindly type in the name of the file and hit Enter? It's ugly, but could work.

Comment: Hi Slanec,                                                                    It is just a "Browse..." button and SilverLight is not accepting JavaScript. I could not type in the Filepath without clicking the Browse button.

Comment: That's what I mean. Click the Browse button, then simulate typing the file path, then pressing Enter. You can use the [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class to simulate typing.

Comment: The click command is just highlighting the Browse button but not able to actually click it./n I tried driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='uploadContainer']/div/div/button[@id='newUploadLnk']"),WaitTime).Click();

Comment: Fun. That's seems like there's no way out. Could you give us an example of the same input on any public site, or create a testing one where we could experiment on it and possibly come up with something worth trying?

Comment: You can find some silverlight objects i.e folders in 'http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/demos/file_explorer.aspx' I haven't tried on clicking them using WebDriver. But it is similar case to check if webdriver click can invoke those Silverlight controls or not.

Answer (score 1):

The file upload methods in WebDriver are intended to work with `<input type='file'>` elements. For working with non-HTML mechanisms of uploading files (which include Silverlight and Flash), you'll need to investigate other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that there's a tool for this for Java applets, I digged and found these:

[There is a tool for using Selenium RC with Silverlight!](http://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/) No idea how well it actually works, but you could give it a try. Yes, I know it's only Selenium RC, but you could try it with [`WebDriverBackedSelenium`](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#webdriver-backed-selenium-rc)...

Scott Hanselman's blog (very readable!) - "abusing" that Silverlight can run `Scriptable` methods. It is written for Selenium IDE, but the same will work for `WebDriver`, too.

[A testing framework for Silverlight.](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut) By Microsoft. Selenium is for webpages, try this for some Silverlight magic.